When developing layer two token like arbitum by modifying an existing erc20. Is it necessary to clone the entire source code repository?
I'm modifying an existing Solidity smart contract, or more accurately taking functionality from multiple different smart contracts and wanted to know if the new contract would pull code from its original source repository if that function has not been modified or must I clone the entire repository of each erc20 contract that I pull function code from?
It is a simple answer, yet I am trying to understand how it all works, but part two of the same question is, would cloning multiple repositories and combining into a new single repository of all the function code potentially cause any issues with time to complete tasks, as in too much data to process. Is it better to have only absolute necessary code? Or does it not have any effect at all? Also is a site like Github the best place to keep said repositories or is there a better choice that would potentially improve the contracts' performance?
So must I clone the entire erc20 & EVM repositories into a new one or just the code I modify and how or can you determine where it pulls code from on a function-by-function basis.
